# Python sqlite Internal Server Error

Tags: python, sqlite, internal-server-error

I'm working on a website powered by Python at the back end. The following script receives values from JavaScript and should write the same to a database.

```
import cgi
import sqlite3

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
brand = form['brand'].value
model = form['model'].value

db = sqlite3.connect("dbase.db")
query = "INSERT INTO requests (brand, model) VALUES (?, ?)"
db.execute(query, (brand, model,))
db.commit()
db.close()
```

But invoking the script returns `500 Internal Server Error`. To my surprise, the following code, run independently on terminal works perfect.

```
import sqlite3

brand = 'nokia'
model = 'lumia 625'

db = sqlite3.connect("dbase.db")
query = "INSERT INTO requests (brand, model) VALUES (?, ?)"
db.execute(query, (brand, model,))
db.commit()
db.close()
```

I'm using Python 2.7.5 and running on Lighttpd server. Also, the `db.execute()` portion is where the error occurs.
How can I correct the problem?

Comment: And do you have an error message? I am willing to bet that `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table requests` is involved.

Comment: Put this at the beginning of your CGI script: `import cgitb; cgitb.enable()`.

Comment: You are using a *relative* path in your `sqlite3.connect()` call; sqlite3 won't complain about not finding a database in whatever the current working directory is that LigHTTPD sets for your script, but it'll be empty and have no tables in it.

Comment: When writing a CGI script, use the [`cgitb` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgitb.html) to make it easier to see the errors produced by your script.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, @Qrtn Enabled `cgitb` and it returns the error `OperationalError: unable to open database file`. Supplying _absolute_ path of database in `sqlite3.connect()` does not help.

Comment: Then you don't have permission to open the file. Remember that CGI scripts are run under a different user account!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: But I can read from the database!

Comment: @sid: on the command line, yes, but then you run the script as a different user.

Comment: @sid: but your server doesn't run with the same privileges as your account (that would be a bad idea); the server user / group does **not** have access to your database file.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The scenario is this: I can read from the database using command line and _cgi_. But I can write onto the database _only_ from the command line.

Comment: @sid: and reading and writing are two different permissions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The access permissions of the database file is such that everyone can read and write it.

Comment: @sid: Yet the error message clearly contradicts you. What are the values of `os.getuid()` and `os.getgid()` in the CGI process? What are the permissions on the directory and the database file *exactly*?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Both `os.getuid()` and `os.getgid()` return _33_. Output of `ls -l dbase.db`: _-rw-rw-rw- 1 sid sid 5120 Apr 14 21:22 dbase.db_

Comment: @sid: and the directory permissions are permissive too?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes. By the way, the script still returns `Internal Server Error`. But, to my surprise, the database is now writable using the CGI script!!

Answer (score 0):

This might happen for not having database `dbase` and table `requests` .You need a database and table for inserting fields.You can create database with this query

```
sqlite3 dbase.db
```

And next you need to create a table for this like

```
create table requests(brand varchar(10), model varchar2(10));
```

Then your file will execute

Comment: I have already created the database. I just want to insert new values into it. The database file and the python script are in the same directory.